# recursive appropriate route selection in list

Tags: c#, recursion, iteration

I want to try to select routes from known points as seen below. But I cannot achieve  to get appropriate route chain for example for point 2 to 8. According to this trial route1-route2 and route3 will be selected, but actually must be only route1 and route3, another example point 1 to point 11, my trial will give result all routes. How can I eliminate unnecessary routes.Is this possible with this trial or should I change my point of view?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var route1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var route2 = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6, 7 };
    var route3 = new List<int> { 1, 8, 9, 10 };
    var route4 = new List<int> { 10, 11, 12, 13 };

    List<List<int>> routeList = new List<List<int>>();
    routeList.Add(route1);
    routeList.Add(route2);
    routeList.Add(route3);
    routeList.Add(route4);

    int start = 3;
    int end = 9;

    var vistedRoutes = new List<List<int>>();

    foreach(var route in routeList.FindAll(r => r.Contains(start)))
    {
        vistedRoutes.Add(route);
        routeList.Remove(route);
        FindPath(vistedRoutes, routeList, start, end);

        if (vistedRoutes.Last().Contains(end))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("done");
}

static void FindPath(List<List<int>> visitedRoutes, List<List<int>> remainingRoutes, int start, int end)
{
    if (visitedRoutes.Last().Contains(end))
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < remainingRoutes.Count; i++ )
    {
        var route = remainingRoutes[i];

        foreach (var point in route)
        {
            if (visitedRoutes.Last().Contains(point))
            {
                visitedRoutes.Add(route);
                var newRemainingRoutes = new List<List<int>>(remainingRoutes);
                newRemainingRoutes.Remove(route);
                FindPath(visitedRoutes, newRemainingRoutes, start, end);
                if (visitedRoutes.Last().Contains(end))
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    visitedRoutes.Remove(route);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your logic for route selection? Regardless of code, why should point 2 to 8 give route1 and route2? And what should point 1 to 11 give?

Comment: I believe you are going at this the wrong way, have a look a "shortest path" algorithm, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm. It is very hard to give constructive feedback on "it doesn't work".

Comment: @BeemerGuy if my starting point is 2 and end point is 8 then i start with route1 first i go {2-1} then then i pass to route3 to go to 8 {1-8..}  why i select these because they are intersect in point 1

Comment: @flindeberg i know shortest path problem but i have no distances between points, i have only known routes and start and end points.

Comment: Actually you do. You assume `Distance(r1_2,r1_1) == 0`, `Distance(r1_1,r3_1) == 1` and `Distance(r3_1,r3_8) == 0`.